# Updated solution to importing financial information into Excel or Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, google-sheets, powerquery

Does anybody know of an updated solution to import financial statments (balance sheets, income statements, cash flows) from yahoo finance / google finance into excel or google docs?

Since they both changed their API / URLS I have not been able to find a working solution.

Running the following powerquery seems to import the correct data, but its slow and the data gets stored as text and `VALUE()`does not seem to convert to numeric very well.

```
let
    Ticker = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Ticker"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Quelle = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&Ticker&"/balance-sheet?p="&Ticker&"")),
    Data = Quelle{2}[Data],
    FirstRowHeader = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data)
in
    FirstRowHeader
```

I can´t seem to get it working with `importhtml` in google docs either.

EDIT: I have the following excel data. Just edit the symbol in the `sheet` `FinalData` in column 1 and row 1 and refresh the queries. (currently HOG is the symbol loaded, type GOOG, MSFT etc.). To refresh the queries, go to `Data`>> `show queries`.

[Link to file](https://ufile.io/qaccc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When stuck, start over…** <sub>(especially since you said the site you're scraping the data from has changed.)</sub>

I'm using Access 2016.  If you're using a different version the steps might vary slightly.

1. **On the `Data` tab, click <kbd>From Web</kbd>** (in the *Get & Transform Data* group)

   [image: pic1]
2. **Paste in your source URL**, ie: `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/msft/balance-sheet?p=msft`

   [image: pic2]
3. **Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and wait for the Navigator to load**.

   [image: pic3]
4. **Click the table you want** (**`2`**, I think) **and then click <kbd>Load</kbd>**

   [image: pic4]

The data will load onto a new worksheet.

If desired, you can [add parameters](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/) to the query (the same way you apparently did before).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is exactly what the powerquery code in the original post was doing. I am able to obtain the information this way, however excel imports the data as a `text` object and `VALUE()` does not work nor does adding a `0` (to try to convert as a number).

Comment: Also this way is very slow (the same as with the powerquery method I originally posted).

Comment: Strange, not slow for me.  Reboot, and then try it in a new (blank) workbook.

Comment: Apologies, its not that it is slow per se, its just that when I use the powerquery tool and your method. I have to refresh the Balance sheet query, the income statement query and cash flow query, to update the results. (I edit my original post to show what I mean).

Comment: So it's *not* running the query that is slow? I'm confused.

Comment: @user113156 - Okay I tried it.  It took 20 seconds to refresh the 3 queries, including the 3 "priavcy" warnings I had to click (that I've never seen before.)  Is that how long it takes on yours?  Is that unreasonable?  How often are you going to be refreshing it? Which country are you in?

Comment: Thanks, the issue is not in regards to speed, I was just hoping that there was a more elegant solution like previous methods. Also this method produces `text` balance sheets, cash flows etc. When I try to convert it to numeric `=BalanceSheet[@[12/31/2017]]+0` or using the `VALUE()` function I get `#VALUE!` errors.

Comment: Yes the privacy warnings I was a little confused with also. But kind of *ignoring* them still works

Comment: Apologies for the constant messages... The 20 second speed is not so unreasonable, I do not mind waiting a short time like 20 seconds to get the results as long as it works, I was hoping to just replace "HOG" to another ticker symbol such as "GOOG" and *instantly* get new balancesheets, cash flows etc. The idea is to run some further calculations on a different `sheet`.

Comment: As for your VALUE Errors, do you mean the column you had filled in next to the data?  This one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kndRf.png ?

Comment: And as for loading instantly, the web page doesn't load instantly in a **browser** either... in fact it never finishes loading since it's auto updating constantly.  Are you saying that's what you want excel to have as well:an instant, live feed?

Comment: Excel did not seem to format the numbers into numeric (if you try and do calculations on, for example; BalanceSheet `B3/B5` it returns `#VALUE!`

Comment: The current model is fine, more than sufficient for what I need it for right now. If I have to click `refresh` 3 times, this is no problem. Regarding your image, I am able to copy as you did into a black space, but calculations do not seem to work

Comment: =B3/B5 works absolutely fine for me.  I put it in I3 and even copied it right and down.  See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMJA6.png

Comment: and **I didn't copy any of those cell** the previous picture was **your** existing formulas.  All i did was make the column wider because the cells showed ###### since the column was too skinny

Comment: Hmm thats strange... Would it be possible to upload your excel file to a filesharing website like https://uploadfiles.io - then I can check it with my file

Comment: Dude, IT'S YOUR FILE!  I didn't change anything!   Hang on I will show you.  Are you maybe somewhere that the `.` isn't the decimal separator?

Comment: I'm about to post an animated GIF showing exactly what i did when i opened the file.  Are you confused because the data is automatically going into a **table** and maybe you haven't worked with tables before?  I'm confused because I dont understand what your issue is -- I don't see any problems.

Comment: No I think you may be right, it could be something now to do with I am using `,` as a separator and not a `.`

Comment: check this out: https://image.ibb.co/gOAvVH/tmp_qry.gif   are you making the column wider like I did? (To get rid of the `#####`)  Do you realize why a few of the cells have Errors?  (because they're doing math on cells that are empty or have text in cell) but most of the cells calculate fine.

Comment: or, if it is the decimal separator, check this out https://gxcuf89792.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/24472i7195C57E14E5D2FB/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

Comment: Dude! X-D that was the most ELI5 demonstration I have ever had, thanks! - I just solved the problem, the problem was to do with my global settings in excel configured for a Spanish system not a US/UK system. I changed the default `Use System separators` to `,` and the `. ` and its working now.

Comment: see [this page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Formulas-and-Functions/Convert-input-decimal-separator-from-API-source-to-non-English/td-p/129359) and [this page](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/05/25/working-with-international-date-and-number-formats-in-power-query/) and also [this page](https://www.google.ca/search?q=power+query+web+data+comma+decimal+separator)